# Pass environment variable through service in Kubernetes?

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes

Is there a way to pass environment variables through the services in Kubernetes?

I tried passing it in to my service yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: kafka
  name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9092
    selector:
      name: kafka
  env:
    - name: BROKER_ID
      value: "1"
```

The service is being consumed by kubectl, and is created.

I've confirmed the service is connected to my container through `env | grep KAFKA` and the output of variables greatly increase, as expected when my service is up.

However, I would like to pass in custom environment-variables that have to be different depending on which instance of the container it is in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that Kubernetes is designed has Services decoupled from Pods.  You can not inject a Secret or an env var into a running Pod.  What you want is to configure the Pod to use the env var or Secret.

Comment: This post is related to [Kafka on Kubernetes multi-node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140025/kafka-on-kubernetes-multi-node).
So what I'm trying to do is to ensure a broker-id for Kafka-nodes that can be passed to the master-node and Zookeeper. Someone came up with the idea of using the stripped Pod-ips for this. Do you have any better suggestions? 
The issue is of course that Kubernetes inherently doesn't guarantee that a single Pod is alive "forever", but config-files in Zookeeper is based on static configurations.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way I've found so far: (reading required)
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4710

Roughly, create a secret in a file that's mounted and source it before you execute your script.

Comment: Could you provide an example?
Do I replace the "env" with "secret", and reference a secret volume somehow?
Is this more focused on Openshift, vs standalone Kubernetes? PS: I read the thread last time you posted as well, but I can't really figure it out. :)

Comment: If you read down in the ticket link there's an example, search for "Example of current way it can be done today"

Comment: This ends up being a pretty good way to create dynamic environmental variables.