# Kubernetes: how to using '--add-host'?

Tags: kubernetes

my project need add 1 line to /etc/hosts, with docker i did:

`docker run --rm --add-host=kafka:10.0.x.xx kafka/backend`

I want add config in replication controller but can't find config or env.

Pls suggest to me solution ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's nothing directly comparable to Docker's `--add-host`, which really only adds an entry to `/etc/hosts`, in your case `kafka 10.0.x.x`, but [here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140025/kafka-on-kubernetes-multi-node) that contains answers that should be helpful for your case (assuming a few things here since you didn't provide a context what you want to achieve).